# How to change Sklearn flavors version in mlflow on azure machine learning?

Tags: python, azure, scikit-learn, azure-machine-learning-service, mlflow

I need to change the flavors "sklearn_version" in mlflow from "0.22.1" to "1.0.0" on azure machine learning when I log my trained model, since this model will be incompatible with the sklearn version that I am using for deployment during inference. I could change the version of sklearn in conda.yml file by setting "conda_env" in

`mlflow.sklearn.log_model(conda_env= 'my_env')`

[image]

here is the screen shot of requirements.txt
[image]

however, sklearn version under flavors in MLmodel file remains unchanged and that is the file that causes problem:

[image]

and here is script that I use to create this mlflow experiment in azure machine learning notebooks.

```
import mlflow
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

from azureml.core import Workspace
from azureml.core.model import Model
from azureml.mlflow import register_model


def run_model(ws, experiment_name, run_name, x_train, y_train):
    
    # set up MLflow to track the metrics
    mlflow.set_tracking_uri(ws.get_mlflow_tracking_uri())
    mlflow.set_experiment(experiment_name)  
    
    with mlflow.start_run(run_name=run_name) as run:
        
        # fit model
        regression_model = DecisionTreeRegressor()
        regression_model.fit(x_train, y_train)
    
        # log training score 
        training_score = regression_model.score(x_train, y_train)
        mlflow.log_metric("Training score", training_score)

        my_conda_env = {
                    "name": "mlflow-env",
                    "channels": ["conda-forge"],
                    "dependencies": [
                        "python=3.8.5",
                        {
                            "pip": [
                                "pip",
                                "scikit-learn~=1.0.0",
                                "uuid==1.30",
                                "lz4==4.0.0",
                                "psutil==5.9.0",
                                "cloudpickle==1.6.0",
                                "mlflow",
                            ],
                        },
                    ],
                }

        
        # register the model
        mlflow.sklearn.log_model(regression_model, "model", conda_env=my_conda_env)

    model_uri = f"runs:/{run.info.run_id}/model"
    model = mlflow.register_model(model_uri, "sklearn_regression_model")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # connect to your workspace
    ws = Workspace.from_config()

    # create experiment and start logging to a new run in the experiment
    experiment_name = "exp_name"

    # mlflow run name
    run_name= '1234'

  
    # get train data
    x_train, y_train  = get_train_data()
    
    run_model(ws, experiment_name, run_name, x_train, y_train)
```

Any idea how can change the flavor sklearn version in MLmodel file from **"0.22.1"** to **"1.0.0"** in my script?

With many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The modifications of the versions must be from **`"requirements.txt"`**. We need to manually override the versions we need and move the build to the pipeline.

Manually edit the following code

```
conda_env = {
    'channels': ['conda-forge'],
    'dependencies': [
        'python=3.8.8',
        'pip'],
    'pip': [
        'mlflow',
        'scikit-learn==0.23.2',
        'cloudpickle==1.6.0'
    ],
    'name': 'mlflow-env'
}
mlflow.sklearn.log_model(model, "my_model", conda_env=conda_env)
```

The below code should be in conda.yml

```
name: mlflow-env
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
- python=3.8.8
- pip
- pip:
  - mlflow
  - scikit-learn==0.23.2
  - cloudpickle==1.6.0
```

The following code block must be there in python_env.yaml

```
python: 3.8.8
build_dependencies:
  - pip==21.1.3
  - setuptools==57.4.0
  - wheel==0.37.0
dependencies:
  - -r requirements.txt
```

The following thing must be there in requirements.txt

```
mlflow
scikit-learn==0.23.2
cloudpickle==1.6.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer, however I did not quite understand your answer. I can change the conda.yml file when I specify the config under ```conda_env``` variable however the "MLmodel" file remains unchanged as I showed it in my screenshot. Furthermore, I can either give configuration of "requirement.txt" or "conda_env" at a time to  ```mlflow.sklearn.log_model(model, "my_model", conda_env=conda_env)``` and once the model is logged in mlflow I cannot change the requirements.txt manually. Could you please share the python script that you use to (like mine) to change all the configs. tnx!

Comment: one more question, could you please kindly also share where I should define and use "python_env.yaml" within my script? thanks in advance!

Comment: Already shared in the answer. Once verify each section.

Comment: Need to manually configure the requirements.txt. Before running the pipeline we need to satisfy the requirements.txt. Process according to the requirements.txt

Comment: once the model is logged in your experiment you cannot change the requirements.txt file, and  as I stated, you can either give the requirements.txt to mlflow.sklearn.log_model(model, "my_model", pip_requirements=["-r requirements.txt"]) or conda_env not both at the same time. I still didn't understand, where did you used "python_env.yaml" in your code? not  "python_env.yaml"  is generated under "model" directory in mlflow outputs.

Comment: Yes, we need to do it manually before logged in. 

https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/models.html

Check the link mentioned above for reference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245760/discussion-between-saeid-hedayati-and-sairamtadepalli-mt).

Comment: could you please take a look at my initial screenshot? as you can see no python_env.yml gets generated each time I log my model. only "conda.yml", "MLmodel", "model.pkl", "requirements.txt" were generated. So, no "python_env.yml". I think the documentation is outdated. As I said before, I can set the conda_env and correspondingly the ```conda.yml```and ```requirements.txt``` also shows the correct config. 
when I define dependencies under "conda_env". Only "MLmodel", flavors remained unchanged and that is the only thing I need to change.

Comment: According to different sources, some of the package's versions are deprecated after log the model. To make favor of running the configuration script internally in Sci-kit learn for the python SDK version. The change we see in the versions is because of wanted deprecation from script running to configuring the experiment.

Comment: Is there a solution for that? How can I upgrade the sklearn version inside the flavors?

Comment: We cannot upgrade the version. It was designed like that. For better execution of the code, the version was deprecated, and it is developed like that only. it is not an error.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to solve this issue. Apparently flavors within mlflow MLfile use the version of installed scikit-learn within the workspace. all I needed to to was to upgrade the scikit-learn from cli within workspace.

1. open cli in azure machine learning notebooks
2. upgarde your intended flavor package. My case was scikit-learn, in my case I used 1.0.2:

```
 pip install --upgrade scikit-learn==1.0.2
```

3. log your model in mlflow by running your training script one more time.
   [image]